# How much slower are strings containing numbers compared to numbers?

Tags: ruby, string, performance, integer

Say I want to take a number and return its digits as an array in Ruby.
For this specific purpose or for string functions and number functions in general, which is faster?

These are the algorithms I assume would be most commonly used:

Using Strings: `n.to_s.split(//).map {|x| x.to_i}`

Using Numbers:

```
array = []
until n = 0
    m = n % 10
    array.unshift(m)
    n /= 10 
end
```

Comment: `String#to_i` isn't the only way to get from a string to an integer. Have you tried benchmarking `Integer()`?

Comment: just note that any answer would depend on a specific ruby implementation & version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steven's response is impressive, but I looked at it for a couple minutes of and couldn't distill it into a simple answer, so here is mine.

### For Fixnums

It is fastest to use the digits method I provide below. It's also pretty quick (and much easier) to use `num.to_s.each_char.map(&:to_i)`.

---

### For Bignums

It is fastest to use `num.to_s.each_char.map(&:to_i)`.

---

### The Solution

If speed is *honestly* the determining factor for what code you use (meaning [don't be evil](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/)), then **this code is the best choice** for the job.

```
class Integer
  def digits
    working_int, digits = self, Array.new
    until working_int.zero?
      digits.unshift working_int % 10
      working_int /= 10
    end
    digits
  end
end

class Bignum
  def digits
    to_s.each_char.map(&:to_i)
  end
end
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/1041393) are the approaches I considered to arrive at this conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for adding in the "short answer"! I would be very interested to see what the answer is for a lower-level solution. Presumably, figuring out each digit is a subset of the work required to actually print out a number, so the integer-based approach is going to be faster. It would be cool to learn what about Ruby's implementation of its Integer classes makes it slower.

Comment: I looked at the internals a bit, still not sure how they're represented internally (my expectation was BCD) but there appears to already be a macro that does most of this task (probably convert the array it returns to a Ruby Array and have a super fast version of this for bignums) https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/include/ruby/ruby.h#L881-884

Answer (score 8):

The difference seems to be less than one order of magnitude, with the integer-based approach faster for `Fixnum`s. For `Bignum`s, the relative performance starts out more or less even, with the string approach winning out significantly as the number of digits grows.

## As strings

### Program

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'profile'

$n = 1234567890
10000.times do
    $n.to_s.split(//).map {|x| x.to_i}
end
```

### Output

```
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
 55.64     0.74      0.74    10000     0.07     0.10  Array#map
 21.05     1.02      0.28   100000     0.00     0.00  String#to_i
 10.53     1.16      0.14        1   140.00  1330.00  Integer#times
  7.52     1.26      0.10    10000     0.01     0.01  String#split
  5.26     1.33      0.07    10000     0.01     0.01  Fixnum#to_s
  0.00     1.33      0.00        1     0.00  1330.00  #toplevel
```

## As integers

### Program

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'profile'

$n = 1234567890
10000.times do
    array = []
    n = $n
    until n == 0
        m = n%10
        array.unshift(m)
        n /= 10
    end
    array
end
```

### Output

```
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
 70.64     0.77      0.77        1   770.00  1090.00  Integer#times
 29.36     1.09      0.32   100000     0.00     0.00  Array#unshift
  0.00     1.09      0.00        1     0.00  1090.00  #toplevel
```

## Addendum

The pattern seems to hold for smaller numbers also. With `$n = 12345`, it was around 800ms for the string-based approach and 550ms for the integer-based approach.

When I crossed the boundary into `Bignum`s, say, with `$n = 12345678901234567890`, I got 2375ms for both approaches. It would appear that the difference evens out nicely, which I would have taken to mean that the internal local powering `Bignum` is string-like. However, the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Bignum.html) seems to suggest otherwise.

For academic purposes, I once again doubled the number of digits to `$n = 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890`. I got around 4450ms for the string approach and 9850ms for the integer approach, a stark reversal that rules out my previous postulate.

## Summary

```
Number of digits | String program | Integer program | Difference
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
5                | 800ms          | 550ms           | Integer wins by 250ms
10               | 1330ms         | 1090ms          | Integer wins by 240ms
20               | 2375ms         | 2375ms          | Tie
40               | 4450ms         | 9850ms          | String wins by 4400ms
```

[image]

Comment: With String#each_byte and each_char you get faster results. Examples can be seen in [my benchmark-solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445496/how-much-slower-are-strings-containing-numbers-compared-to-numbers/6446734#6446734)

Answer (score 1):

I made a solution with 'benchmark' using the code examples of Steven Xu and a String#each_byte-version.

```
require 'benchmark'
MAX = 10_000

#Solution based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445496/how-much-slower-are-strings-containing-numbers-compared-to-numbers/6447254#6447254
class Integer
  def digits
    working_int, digits = self, Array.new
    until working_int.zero?
      digits.unshift working_int % 10
      working_int /= 10
    end
    digits
  end
end

class Bignum
  def digits
    to_s.each_char.map(&:to_i)
  end
end

[
  12345,
  1234567890,
  12345678901234567890,
  1234567890123456789012345678901234567890,
].each{|num|
puts "========="
puts "Benchmark #{num}"
Benchmark.bm do|b|

   b.report("Integer%        ") do
     MAX.times { 
        array = []
        n = num
        until n == 0
            m = n%10
            array.unshift(m)
            n /= 10
        end
        array     
     }
   end

   b.report("Integer% <<     ") do
     MAX.times { 
        array = []
        n = num
        until n == 0
            m = n%10
            array << m
            n /= 10
        end
        array.reverse
     }
   end

   b.report("Integer#divmod  ") do
     MAX.times { 
        array = []
        n = num
        until n == 0
          n, x = *n.divmod(10)
          array.unshift(x)
        end
        array     
     }
   end

   b.report("Integer#divmod<<") do
     MAX.times { 
        array = []
        n = num
        until n == 0
          n, x = *n.divmod(10)
          array << x
        end
        array.reverse
     }
   end

   b.report("String+split//  ") do
     MAX.times { num.to_s.split(//).map {|x| x.to_i} }
   end

   b.report("String#each_byte") do
     MAX.times { num.to_s.each_byte.map{|x| x.chr } }
   end

   b.report("String#each_char") do
     MAX.times { num.to_s.each_char.map{|x| x.to_i } }
   end

   #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445496/how-much-slower-are-strings-containing-numbers-compared-to-numbers/6447254#6447254
   b.report("Num#digit       ") do
     MAX.times { num.to_s.each_char.map{|x| x.to_i } }
   end
 end
}
```

My results:

```
Benchmark 12345
      user     system      total        real
Integer%          0.015000   0.000000   0.015000 (  0.015625)
Integer% <<       0.016000   0.000000   0.016000 (  0.015625)
Integer#divmod    0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.046875)
Integer#divmod<<  0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.031250)
String+split//    0.109000   0.000000   0.109000 (  0.109375)
String#each_byte  0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.046875)
String#each_char  0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.046875)
Num#digit         0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.046875)
=========
Benchmark 1234567890
      user     system      total        real
Integer%          0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.046875)
Integer% <<       0.046000   0.000000   0.046000 (  0.046875)
Integer#divmod    0.063000   0.000000   0.063000 (  0.062500)
Integer#divmod<<  0.062000   0.000000   0.062000 (  0.062500)
String+split//    0.188000   0.000000   0.188000 (  0.187500)
String#each_byte  0.063000   0.000000   0.063000 (  0.062500)
String#each_char  0.093000   0.000000   0.093000 (  0.093750)
Num#digit         0.079000   0.000000   0.079000 (  0.078125)
=========
Benchmark 12345678901234567890
      user     system      total        real
Integer%          0.234000   0.000000   0.234000 (  0.234375)
Integer% <<       0.234000   0.000000   0.234000 (  0.234375)
Integer#divmod    0.203000   0.000000   0.203000 (  0.203125)
Integer#divmod<<  0.172000   0.000000   0.172000 (  0.171875)
String+split//    0.266000   0.000000   0.266000 (  0.265625)
String#each_byte  0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.125000)
String#each_char  0.141000   0.000000   0.141000 (  0.140625)
Num#digit         0.141000   0.000000   0.141000 (  0.140625)
=========
Benchmark 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
      user     system      total        real
Integer%          0.718000   0.000000   0.718000 (  0.718750)
Integer% <<       0.657000   0.000000   0.657000 (  0.656250)
Integer#divmod    0.562000   0.000000   0.562000 (  0.562500)
Integer#divmod<<  0.485000   0.000000   0.485000 (  0.484375)
String+split//    0.500000   0.000000   0.500000 (  0.500000)
String#each_byte  0.218000   0.000000   0.218000 (  0.218750)
String#each_char  0.282000   0.000000   0.282000 (  0.281250)
Num#digit         0.265000   0.000000   0.265000 (  0.265625)
```

String#each_byte/each_char is faster the split, for lower numbers the integer version is faster.